# insert into a ms access database

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

i'm realising a litel program with windows forms c#, that saves data in ms ACCESS database. 
i write this code

```
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Zied\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\testerMSAcceess\testerMSAcceess\bin\Debug\zimed.mdb";
        string fname = textBox1.Text;
        string lname = textBox2.Text;

        connect.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(" INSERT INTO user ([nom],[prenom]) VALUES (@fname,@lname)",connect);



        if (connect.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("ajout ok ");
            connect.Close();
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("ajout ok ");
                connect.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("erreur" + ex.Source);
                connect.Close();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("probleme connection");
        }

    }
```

and i got this error when executing it 
"error in insert methode" 
i have not idea the error in insert request. have you an idea

Comment: It could be that user is an MS Access keyword, so place it also in brackets: INSERT INTO [user]

Comment: Is the provided code correct?
Because when you call the `ExecuteNonQuery` inside the `try/catch` your connection is already closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I added the `using`-statements and `[` `]`-brackets to the query string.

```
string fname = textBox1.Text;
string lname = textBox2.Text;

using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Zied\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\testerMSAcceess\testerMSAcceess\bin\Debug\zimed.mdb"))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [user] ([nom],[prenom]) VALUES (@fname,@lname)", conn))
{
   try
   {
      conn.Open();

      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      MessageBox.Show("ajout ok ");
   }

   catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Erreur" + ex.Source); }

   finally { if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) { conn.Close(); } }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **OLE DB .NET** Provider uses positional parameters that are marked with a question mark (?) instead of named parameters.So, Try to use `?` instead of named parameter. for example.

```
INSERT INTO [user] ([nom],[prenom]) VALUES (?,?)

comand.Parameters.Add("nom", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = fname;
```